# How to use attribute Gravity inside any TextView in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, gravity, linearlayoutmanager

Can you explain me please why my TextView don't work on gravity to left .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B2R8.png)

A: LinearLayout | orientation=HORIZONTAL | gravity A = top  or center or bottom.

B: LinearLayout | orientation=VERTICAL   | gravity B = left or center or right.

C: TextView

i us:

A.setGravity(gravity A);

B.setGravity(gravity B);

Result gravity:

- top    | left :not work (=top center)
- center | left :not work (=center center)
- bottom | left :not work (=bottom center)
- top    | center :work
- center | center :work
- bottom | center :work
- top    | right :work
- center | right :work
- bottom | right :work

  ```
      LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(mContext);

  LinearLayout framelayoutTitle = new LinearLayout(mContext);
  framelayoutTitle.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
  framelayoutTitle.setGravity(vGravityTitle);

  LinearLayout layoutTitle = new LinearLayout(mContext);
  layoutTitle.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
  layoutTitle.setGravity(hGravityTitle);

  holder.textTitle = new TextView(mContext);
  layoutTitle.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


  framelayoutTitle.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((widthTitle * (width - dp2px(widthImageLV))) / 100, dp2px(heightTitle)));    


          holder.textTitle.setText(titleList.get(position));
          holder.textTitle.setGravity(alignmentTextTitle);
          holder.textTitle.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
          holder.textTitle.setTextSize(sizeTitle);
          holder.textTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

  layoutTitle.addView(holder.textTitle);
  framelayoutTitle.addView(layoutTitle);

  parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
  parent.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
  parent.addView(framelayoutTitle);
  ```

Comment: Instead of all these simple XML codes would be 10 times more useful.

Comment: NO i need to move the text view on the all position inside the layout A.
And i don't us XML i us programmatically code

Answer (score 0):

Try this and give padding and margin according to your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:text="A"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="b"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="b"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i don't know your xml code .if it not getting any idea for above code then pl post your code and i make changes and give it.

Comment: NO i need to move the text view on the all position inside the layout A.
And i don't us XML i us programmatically code

Comment: you want to perform user can change textbox position at runtime. it like animation.

Comment: not annimation but just can change the position of textView :
example: if i setGravity like this:

A.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

B.setGravity(Gravity.Left);

normay i wil have result my textView on left and top

Comment: provide your xml code then better idea what you done.

Comment: my code work well just problem with left gravity i can't have textview on left position for other position is work

Comment: i have add the simple code i us this inside adapter grid view

Comment: OK i found a solution i just have problem on initialization of my variable int:

    int hGravityTitle = 1; i have change it to 3 // i don't know what is the problem but it work now


    public void HGravityTitle(int alignment) {
     if(alignment == 1)
       hGravityTitle = 3;//Gravity.LEFT;
     else if(alignment == 2)
       hGravityTitle = 5;//Gravity.RIGHT;
     else 
       hGravityTitle = 1;//Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
       
     }